# Sharing class variables between instances without using static

Tags: c++, class, static-members

I have a hierarchy that goes like this:

```
       Entity
   /     |     \
Player Enemy Weapon
        /\        /  \
    Slime Fly  Sword  Gun
```

etc. And some code:

```
class Entity {
public:
    void LoadModel();
protected:
    Model* model;
}
```

Each Entity class has its own model, or at least, that's how I would like it to work--the problem is that, if I were to make models static to a class, I would have repeated code in *every* derived class to define the static model, then have a virtual function in every class to return it so that the base `Entity` class can use its load function, etc.

So what I would like to do is to be able to use the base class's `LoadModel()` function to load a model for the specific derived class. Is this possible? How would I achieve this?

Comment: Put the models into a dictionary indexed by some kind of entity ID (e.g. its `typeid`)?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the code of the derived class you can call the base class with

```
Derived d;
d.base::LoadModel();
```